# Insert 50 objects in CoreData Table

Tags: ios, core-data

I want to insert 50 values in coredata ta

```
 Question.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface Question : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * question;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * answer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * mcqsa;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * mcqsb;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * mcqsc;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * mcqsd;



Question.m
#import "Question.h"


@implementation Question

@dynamic question;
@dynamic answer;  
@dynamic mcqsa;
@dynamic mcqsb;
@dynamic mcqsc;
@dynamic mcqsd;

@end
```

Insert Code

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];


    Question *question = [NSEntityDescription
                                  insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Question"
                                  inManagedObjectContext:context];
question.question = @"What is capital of Australia?";
question.answer = @"Testville";
question.mcqsa = @"Sydney";
question.mcqsb = @"Canbera";
question.mcqsc =  @"Berlin";
question.mcqsd = @"Bern";

NSError *error;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
.......
```

How can I insert multiple data, 50 questions with their mcqs (50 Question object)?
Is there any manual way using something else?

Answer (score 1):

[MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) a wrapper for CoreData provides some nice import features. You need to include the data that you need to import as plist/json in the bundle.

On the initial run you import data to coreData.

You can find a great tutorial on the same in the following link [Importing data made easy](http://www.cimgf.com/2012/05/29/importing-data-made-easy/)

You need to create subclasses of NSManagedObject

on them you can call `importFromObject:` or `importFromObject:`. If you have full control over the structuring of the data this will happen out of the box without writing a single code for mapping data stored to core data entities.

Answer (score 0):

You need a seed store, Pre-fill core data database then fetch it from device or simulator  document directory and than add it to your bundle. At first run, you would copy database from bundle to Document directory and use that database onwards

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop to insert data.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
for(i=0; i<50; i++) {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];


    Question *question = [NSEntityDescription
                                  insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Question"
                                  inManagedObjectContext:context];
question.question = @"What is capital of Australia?";
question.answer = @"Testville";
question.mcqsa = @"Sydney";
question.mcqsb = @"Canbera";
question.mcqsc =  @"Berlin";
question.mcqsd = @"Bern";

NSError *error;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
.......
}
```

Comment: Isn't it going to save the same data?

Comment: You can add dynamic data and at end of loop 50 records will be added to your database.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Here is the code:

```
  NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"QuesList" ofType:@"plist"];


   NSArray *quesList = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];


    for(NSDictionary *object in quesList){


NSString *str1 = [object objectForKey:@"question"];
NSString *str2 = [object objectForKey:@"answer"];
NSString *str3 = [object objectForKey:@"mcqsa"];
NSString *str4 = [object objectForKey:@"mcqsb"];
NSString *str5 = [object objectForKey:@"mcqsc"];



 Question *question = [NSEntityDescription
                          insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Question"
                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
question.question = str1;
question.answer =str2;
question.mcqsa =str3;
question.mcqsb =str4;
question.mcqsc =  str5;

  }
```

And

Also make sure that you run this code only once, otherwise it woudld create duplicate objects